# My ubuntu crashes and an error screen appears

Tags: wireless, broadcom

My ubuntu crashes after it has started and it prints some weird stuff like on DOS.

I tried using Ubuntu rescue remix but it said that there were some firmware missing

```
b43-open/ucode.fw;b43/ucode.fw
```

It then directed me to a website to download the firmware. How am I supposed to install them when my Ubuntu crashes every time I start?

Comment: Can you tell us what version of Ubuntu you have installed?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run in recovery mode :

1. Switch on your computer.
2. Wait until the BIOS has finished loading, or has almost finished. (During this time you will probably see a logo of your computer manufacturer.)
3. Quickly press and hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, which will bring up the GNU GRUB menu. (If you see the Ubuntu logo, you've missed the point where you can enter the GRUB menu.)

For full instructions, see the wiki for [Recovery Mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode) instructions.